# Javascript jQuery . Add class when the same data-date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have two tables

```
 <table>
     <tr>
       <td class="myclass" data-date="2015-07-09"> Some text </td>
     </tr>
 </table>

 <table>
    <tr>
       <td data-date="2015-07-09"> Text </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

What I want to do is:

Firstly take the class 'myclass' and add to it one new class 'newclass' . I can easily do it by `$('.myclass').addClass('newclass');`

Secondly I want to search the DOM if there is a < td > which has the same data-date with the .myclass < td > and add also to the newly found < td > the .newclass

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
 $('td[data-date='+$('.myclass').data('date')+']').addClass('newclass');
```

This will satisfy the both condition you are looking for. i.e. adding class to both the td elements.

`$('.myclass').data('date')` will get the date for myclass element. and attribute value selector to target all the td elments that have same data as that of myclass including myclass itself.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it looks great :) There is no need to assign classes differently for two tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
$('.myclass').each(function () {
    $('td[data-date="' + $(this).attr('data-date') + '"]').addClass('newclass');
}):
```

This will add the new class to each element with the same data-date, including the original one with `myclass`

Also, this would work fine even if you have multiple rows with a `myclass` - assuming your question was made more basic than your actual need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("td[data-date='2015-07-09']").addClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more simple if you give an `id` to your tables.
Like `first-table-name` and `second-table-name`.

In this case you will be able to do this with this code:

```
$("#first-table-name .myclass").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("newClass");
    $("#second-table-name td[data-date='" + $(this).data('date') + "']").addClass("newClass");
});
```